# More elegant coffeescript loop

Tags: coffeescript

JS:

```
for(i=this.current.arr.length;i<this.counterLength;i++){
    dosomthing();
    dosomethingelse();
}
```

COFFEE:

```
i = @current.arr.length
while i < @counterLength
  dosomthing()
  dosomethingelse()
  i++
```

I know coffeescript has great loop syntax candy, but I can't find a more elegant way of writing it than this. Is there a more coffeescripty way of doing this?

I know about:

```
 for currentArr in current.arr
 //and
 for currentArr, 1 in current.arr
```

but i needs to start at @currentLength and not 0

Comment: Are you trying to iterate trough an array from the end to beginning? A.K.A in reverse? What is `this.counterLength` ?

Comment: I am trying to iterate `@currentLenght-@current.arr.length` times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[..]` operator is what you are looking for:

```
start = this.current.arr.length
end = this.counterLength
for [start...end]
    dosomthing()
    dosomethingelse()
```

No need to predefine `start` and `end`, I just used it to make the code a bit clearer. Note that if `start` is greater then `end`, then it will go backwards.

Actually you need `[...]` operator, because you used `<` instead of `<=` in the code. The `[...]` operator excludes the last element.

Comment: Can you link me to some documentation of this operator? I've never heard of it, but it looks down right neato!

Comment: @Fresheyeball Official CoffeeScript documentation: http://coffeescript.org/#slices

Comment: Follow up question. Do I need `i` as its not in use beyond constructing the loop?

Comment: I just checked and we can exclude `i` all together!

Comment: @Fresheyeball Oh, I didn't know that. I've learned something myself. :) Thanks!

Comment: `The [...] operator excludes the last element.` That's what I was looking for! `<` not `<=`!